# Display column that has a specific string

Tags: grep, columns, cut

Content of a sample file is as follow:

```
AA BB CC DD BB
1  2  3  4  9
5  6  7  8  10
```

I want to display the whole columns that contain `BB` and `DD`. In the real case, I do not know which columns contain the strings `BB` and `DD`. And additionally, it will be great to determine order of the columns that will be printed.

The desired output is:

```
BB DD BB
2  4  9
6  8  10
```

When it is said that `DD` column must be first, the desired output is:

```
DD BB BB
4  2  9
8  6  10
```

Column ordering may given in a string e.g. `cols="BB, DD"`.

Delimiter of the input file may change.

Answer (score 5):

You might run into problems with `cut` if you have multiple spaces as the delimiter.  You could use `awk`:

```
$ awk '{print $2, $4, $5}' OFS='\t' inputfile
BB      DD      BB
2       4       9
6       8       10
```

(You could supply the input and output delimiter using `FS` and `OFS` respectively.)

---

EDIT: As per your comments, if the values are in unknown columns you could say:

```
awk 'NR==1{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i=="BB" || $i=="DD") {a[i]++;} } { for (i in a) printf "%s\t", $i; printf "\n"}' filename
```

For your input, it'd result in:

```
BB      DD      BB
2       4       9
6       8       10
```

It works by keeping a track of the columns in the first row containing `BB` or `DD` and then printing out those columns.

If you intend to use a variable for storing the column values, you could declare one like:

```
pattern="^BB$|^DD$"
```

(note that the anchors `^` & `$` have been added to ensure that `BB` doesn't match `ABB` and so on.  `|` is, again, a regex metacharacter denoting `or`)

and then say:

```
awk -vp="$pattern" 'NR==1{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i~p) {a[i]++;} } { for (i in a) printf "%s\t", $i; printf "\n"}' filename
```

Comment: Dear @devnull, I have updated my question. The column indices are not known beforehand.

Comment: Dear @devnull, it is a very good solution! Is it possible to get column names from a variable such as `cols="BB, DD"` or `cols="BB DD"` and display the columns in the order they appear in the variable?

Comment: @Kadir I've added an update.  Please attempt to provide all information in the question in one go in the future.

Comment: Dear @devnull, `pattern="^BB$|^DD$"` and pattern="^DD$|^BB$" give the same column ordering. Is it possible to display the columns in the order they appear in the variable named `pattern`.

Comment: Dear @Kadir, As I mentioned earlier, __do not__ keep revising your question until eternity.  If you are not clear of what you want to ask, don't post a question in the first place.